# Negative variance with expected value calculation

Tags: statistics

I am currently trying to calculate the variance of the equation $2.1x^{-3.1}$ for x$\geq1$, and 0 for x<1. Given that the equation for variance is $E(x^2)-E(x)^2$, I first found that $E(x)$ is equal to 1.909.  Then, I found that $E(x^2)$ is equal to 0.5.  Therefore, the variance is calculated to be $0.5-1.909^2$, or -3.144. What I don't understand is how the variance could be negative. Was there an error in my calculations or is the negative variance permissible?

Comment: Your calculation of $E(X^2)=0.5$ is clearly wrong as $X^2\ge X \ge 1$ with probability $1$ with this density function

Comment: With the negative exponent, wouldn't a larger x value result in a smaller number?  $2.1/x^{6.2}$ should be less than $2.1/x^{3.1}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathsf E(x^2)~{=\int_\Bbb R x^2~f(x)~\mathrm dx\\[1ex]=\int_1^\infty 2.1 x^{-1.1}~\mathrm dx~\\[1ex]=21x^{-0.1}\vert_{x=1}^{\infty}\\[1ex]=21}$

Comment: How did you obtain the original equation?  Given that the expected value function is $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x f(x)$, wouldn't $E(x^2)=\int_{1}^{\infty} x*2.1(x^2)^{-3.1}dx$

Comment: You have the square on the wrong $x$.

Comment: $\mathsf E(g(x))=\int_\Bbb R g(x)~f(x)~\mathrm d x$